# MS Access Calculated Field - Creating dynamic expression

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns

I need to be able to create an ID CODE from the plant name to be in the format of AAAA_AAAAAAAAA_A00000 (A for alpha). Some thing like this;

*Acacia dealbata* 
*ACAC_DEALBATA_T00001*

I can do the first section using `Left([FieldName],4)` but the middle section I'm having trouble with as it will differ depending on the remaining number of words in the name.

*Acer palmatum Atropurpureum* would become *ACER_PALMAATRO_T00002*

*Acer palmatum Dissectum Rubrum* would become *ACER_PALDISRUB_T00003*

My attempt at the middle section is;

`IIf(Len([FieldName]) - Len(Replace([FieldName], " ", "")) + 1 = 2, Mid([FieldName], InStr(1, [FieldName], " "), (9 / (Len([FieldName]) - Len(Replace([FieldName], " ", ""))))), "")`

And returns the following [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEGER.png).

The end section depends on the SUPPLIER of the image of the plant and is given a specific prefix; L, H, or R. Followed by the records autonumber in the table. This prefix is stored in another table I have called SUPPLIER.

I do not know how to collect values from fields of other tables into another so any advice on this is appreciated.

If anyone is able to help please.

Comment: Please share your own attempt. We're not a coding service, you can ask specific questions here, but you can't offload such a large and localized problem to us.

Comment: I'm glad you're attempting to improve your question, but please include what's working, and what's not working with this section of code. Share the current output, and, if possible, be specific about _why_ it's difficult to get it to produce the expected output.

Comment: You will probably be much better served if you create a VBA function that generates the ID CODE, than by trying to generate it with SQL alone.

Comment: Replace() function is not available to Calculated type field. Do this in query, not table. And as @SunKnight0 points out, since the structure of the data varies, will need a VBA custom function.

Comment: You'll need several UDF to accomplish this. You need to cound how many words contains each name, and then, divide that value by 9 (characters allowed by AAAAAAAAA). If result of that division is integer, that's the name of characters you need to extract from each word (skkiping first one): Example: *palmatum Dissectum Rubrum * = 3 words. 9/3 = 3 first chars of each word. In case of *palmatum Atropurpureum* = 2 words, so 9/2 = 4,5, so round up for first word (PALMA) and round down for next words (ATRO). And this is just the beggining! And of course, if you never ever have more than 9 words!